# Exact chance of a Hidden Ability Pokemon from a horde?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Like the title states, what is the **exact** chance that a Pokemon from a horde battle will have its hidden ability?

Comment: I don't think there's anything official on this, so you'll probably end up with a bunch of guesses as answers...

Comment: Well then for the moment,guesses will do

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can find an official source for that chance, but I can give you a pretty good alternative. I've found [this question](http://pokemondb.net/pokebase/167370/what-chance-pokemon-from-horde-battle-will-have-hidden-ability) on Pokemon Database which is what you're looking for.

Since we can't check the actual chance, a guy tried an experiment testing 200 Whismur hordes, which gives a total of 1,000 individual Whismur. That's a pretty good sample.

> What were my results? Well, 952 Whismur had the ability Soundproof and 48 had Rattled. Since I am only interested in the Hidden Ability for this, then 48/1000 = 0.048 or 4.8%
>
> So from this experiment I got the chance of a Pokémon in a Horde with its Hidden Ability is 4.8%. Since GameFreak seems to like round numbers, I suggest the actual answer is probably 5% then.

That's not an official answer, but we can easily assume that the chance of finding a Pokemon from a horde with its *Hidden Ability* is **5%**.